# Parentheses in Python's method calling

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a simple Python code

```
for item in sorted(frequency, key=frequency.get, reverse=True)[:20]:
  print(item, frequency[item])
```

However, if call `frequency.get()` instead of `frequency.get`, it will give me the error of `"get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0"`

I came from Ruby. In Ruby `get` and `get()` would be exactly the same. Is it not the same in Python?

For example, here is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm the description of `get()` and not `get`. What is `get`?

Comment: Well, both the syntax *and* operations are different .. so, no, they are not the same. Start with a tutorial and accept the language for what it is. Ruby methods works by *message passing* - extra work has to be done to get a `Method` - but Python methods work by *direct function evaluations*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`frequency.get` describes the method itself, while `frequency.get()` actually calls the method (and incorrectly gives it no arguments). You are right that this is different than Ruby.

For example, consider:

```
frequency = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
x = frequency.get("a")
```

In this case, `x` is equal to `1`. However, if we did:

```
x = frequency.get
```

`x` would now be a function. For instance:

```
print x("a")
# 1
print x("b")
# 2
```

This function is what you are passing to `sorted`.

Comment: The rough Python -> Ruby equivalents are: `get` -> `:get`, `frequency.get` -> `frequency.method(:get)`, `frequency.get()` -> `frequency.get`. Ruby does implicit calling, so it needs some other syntax to reference the method itself; Python does explicit calling, meaning it needs parentheses for a call, but therefore doesn't need any special syntax to reference a function. This is a tradeoff, so different languages do it differently.

Comment: And I know someone will comment that it's not really a tradeoff, if you just curry all functions like, say, Haskell—that's true, it's just a different tradeoff makes this one irrelevant.